# Local etale cohomology for sheaves of abelian groups.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology, etale-cohomology, local-cohomology

I have seen local cohomology (cohomology supported on a closed subspace) in different contexts, like for topological spaces and for quasi-coherent sheaves on a scheme. I was wondering whether the same naïve definition (i.e. taking the global sections of an injective resolution that are supported on the closed subspace) gives the correct local cohomology for let's say sheaves of abelian groups on the etale site of a scheme? (by the correct the definition I means fitting into a long exact sequence of cohomology groups of the space itself and the complement of the support.)

Comment: You can generalise the definition for more details look at page91 of milne book. I'm not sure what do you mean about injective resulotion supported on closed subspace because sheafs usually don't have such resolution, you have to take an injective resolution and the take$i^!$, and I'm not sure if this is equivalent to taking$i^!$ of the sheaf and then taking injective resolution

Comment: @ali I am not sure what you exactly mean, sheaves of abelian groups have injective resolutions and support of each section of an etale sheaf is closed so it makes sense to talk about sections support on some specific closed sub-scheme. For the latter see: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04FQ   (I mean take the injective resolution and instead of taking global sections take global section supported on some specific closed sub-scheme)

Comment: as I said by this definition you can also compute local cohomology for etale sheaves. I though you mean an injective resolution that supported on a closed subspace which does not exist unless your sheaf is defined on that subspace.

Comment: taking global sections that are supported in $Z$ is basically  $i^{!}$ that I mention in my first  comment

Comment: I see, the upper shriek functor is tricky it does not always give the sections supported on a closed space, but in this case it seems that it does. (Which in that case long exact sequence should follow from the famous shriek short exact sequence)

Comment: yes in coherent sheaf it is a little different but the etale world is more like topological spaces than coherent sheaves

Comment: Sorry for the plug, but it’s possible the blog post I wrote here might help. https://ayoucis.wordpress.com/2019/11/27/punctured-disks-and-punctured-curves-and-cohomology-oh-my-part-ii-cohomology-with-supports/